# How to detect if a user is running IE 6?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

I need to be able to tell if a page is being viewed in IE 6. How can I do this in javascript while ignoring version like 7, 8, or other browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

straight from the [horse's mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509.aspx) (and one googling away):

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: +1: I actully used this in combination with mkoryak's answer.

Comment: This is a better approach - since it gives the "right" result on other browsers that use the IE6 engine and is immune to user-agent spoofing. Better yet would likely be to use feature AKA object detection instead of user agent detection - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: you know, the link i provided has all of this information, about conditional comments, and feature detection, even some hacks